# IE9 how to trace "Internet explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors."

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ssl-certificate

I have a website that IE9 says "Internet explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors."

I have no idea what errors it's talking about however. Firefox correctly shows the site is secure and that all content is correctly served over HTTPS. The certificate is not expired. The certificate is a standard nonwildcard certificate and the application is hosted correctly on the domain and not an invalid subdomain.

Clicking the show content button that trails the warning message will refresh the page, however upon the page loading it immediately shows the dialog again. Clicking show content, rinse and repeat infinite loop.

Why does IE make things so difficult? Can someone tell me how to find equivalent information that I can from Firefox by clicking on the certificate in the Firefox url bar that lets me see the addresses of all of the images/jss/css on the page that lets me verify they are all https in Firefox.

Comment: What's the root certificate in the signing chain?

Comment: @SLaks this is what you're looking for correct? OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
O = Equifax
C = US

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem is not with Internet Explorer, but the generic validation of certificates, I was able to debug this with Chrome's "Console" interface (Developer Tools via F12).  The URLs which were causing the SSL error were listed with the console error "Failed to load resource", and the URL was given.

Internet Explorer's "console" interface never listed these errors.  Fiddler also did not indicate there was an error with the cert in any way (I'm guessing because its job is to monitor the retrieval of the content, rather than deciding what's valid).

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 and look at the console for information about which URL has a problem. Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) will show a popup message about what specifically is wrong with a given certificate.

Comment: Well the console doesn't seem to help. No messages, all of the content from capturing on network shows to be relative or specific to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs in IE7,8,9 and relates to how IE handles *Mixed Content* compared to other browsers.

The message

"Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors."

occurs when a page implementing https links in a script served over http. Chrome & Firefox suppress such mixed content messages.

Possible causes:

1. linking to a javascript file using http protocol
2. linking to a javascript file that does not exist
3. linking to a javascript file over https but attempts to redirect to http
4. inserting references to javascript at run time.

IE users seem to be use to seeing this message on sites like facebook so many will click and  get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at:

[Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889357/internet-explorer-blocked-this-website-from-displaying-content-with-security-cer)

As long as i can imagine, IE is probably complaining about contents that are loaded via JavaScript.
If the same content(picture or similar) where loaded by normal html request(e.g. during the first page loading), it probably wouldn't bother you.