# Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl

I have a security certificate hosted by a CDN provider.  The website is https:www.connect4fitness.com

Navigating to the site in IE gives the following error:

```
"Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors."
```

When I pull the site up in firefox or chrome, everything works fine. But I do see a warning about "Mixed content" and "Partially encrypted content" when I probe the certificate details.

All the outbound links on the site are https.  It's probably some content injected by the CDN that is triggering the message.  But how do I pinpoint the exact part of the webpage that is not being encrypted?  I need that information to work with the Tech Support of the CDN company as they are claiming everything is fine.

Are there any tools or techniques that I can use to find out which part of the rendered page received by the browser was NOT encrypted?

**Additional information:**

Purging the CDN cache resolved the error messages for Firefox and Chrome.  IE still complains about mixed content though I do not see any "http" requests going out on the Network tab.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked if the top of the certificate chain presented by the web site is a trusted CA in MSIE's list?

Comment: Celada - thanks for the note.  Yes the CA is well known.  The main issue is that IE complains about mixed content.  I just checked and even Firefox provides the same message in Technical Details but it does not impact the user experience; the information is available only when you look at certificate details.

Comment: Folks - Two people flagged this question as not related to programming.  I am not sure how debugging and debugging tools are not related to programming.  If you are a moderator, please help keep the question open if you think this is an issue programmers can raise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

I had javascript plugin for client-side exception logging (exceptionhub).  This plugin inserted runtime JS to make an https call to it's servers for logging and got a certificate error.  Apparently only IE found this objectionable as the other browsers did not complain.

In the end I just got rid of the plugin because per their website they took care of the issue when they last had it ([See here](http://help.exceptionhub.com/discussions/problems/16-ssl-error-in-ie6)).  I think it probably recurred and I am not about to experiment with it as it was a nice-to-have plugin.

Comment: It is a really interesting feature of Firefox and Chrome to just cancel the request silently, while IE at least complains about it.

Answer (score 3):

The actual issue that was triggering the mixed content error on IE was a broken link to an included hosted javascript file.  The call was https but it did not result in 200 response and that somehow made IE stop issuing further calls as it tried to load the page.  I removed this call and then IE loaded the full page without any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `http://` links in a page served over `https://`. The fact that it doesn't impact the user experience in Firefox is more of a Firefox bug than anything else; ideally, it should. (One other problem with Firefox, unless it has changed recently, is that it will only show the warning after having sent the request anyway.)

Use Chrome's Developer Tools or Firebug (Network tab) to find out which resources are loaded with plain HTTP and use `https://` URIs instead. (You may need to use a CDN that supports HTTPS.)

Comment: Bruno - thanks!  That helped. However, purging the CDN cache resolved the error messages for Firefox and Chrome.  IE still complains about mixed content though I do not see any "http" requests going out on the Network tab.  Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the run-time tools are in agreement with the manual page inspection - there are no http calls from the page. This probably is an IE bug.  I found some old IE 7/8 related forum entries about similar issues.  I am not sure how it can be resolved but I can close this out. Thanks for your help.